# Installing Sloeber in custom folder on Mac OS

Tags: arduino

I've installed Sloeber 3.1 in custom folder within my home directory. I do not want to move it into Applications.

After starting I'm getting this error:

```
The plugin Needs write access to /private/var/folders/s7/hmdxddrn7dg6ccjf6yz1bk9m0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/498C6D5E-9AFA-4D78-8EEC-8BC0DBBEC42A/d/sloeber-3.1.app/Contents/Eclipse/arduinoPlugin
```

On terminal when I try to create folder within this directory I'm getting: `Read-only file system`

What is the reason for read only file system? How can I solve it (without moving Sloeber into Applications) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac has implemented some rules for download safety that affects you.
More info about the Mac security change can found here http://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/app-translocation.html
**extract from the link**
I was looking through the misnamed "What's New in OS X" document, and something caught my eye under "Security and Privacy Enhancements":

> Starting in OS X v10.12, you can no longer provide external code or
>   data alongside your code-signed app in a zip archive or unsigned disk
>   image. An app distributed outside the Mac App Store runs from a
>   randomized path when it is launched and so cannot access such external
>   resources.

This is further explained in the equally misnamed "OS X Code Signing In Depth":

> If using a disk image to ship an app, users should drag the app from
>   the image to its desired installation location (usually /Applications)
>   before launching it. This also applies to apps installed via ZIP or
>   other archive formats or apps downloaded to the Downloads directory:
>   ask the user to drag the app to /Applications and launch it from
>   there.